# What will be the result of the following connection scenario in an MQTT network?

Tags: mqtt

In MQTT it is the client who initiates the connection with a CONNECT message.

[image: MQTT Connect Package parameters]

The first field of the packet is the `clientId`:

> The client identifier (short ClientId) is an identifier of each MQTT client connecting to a MQTT broker. As the word identifier already suggests, it should be unique per broker. The broker uses it for identifying the client and the current state of the client. (Image and quote are taken from from [here](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-3-client-broker-connection-establishment).)

Now let's say I have two clients, client X and Y in the following situation.

1. Broker launched, no clients yet.
2. X succesfully connects to the broker with `client-1` id, username is `X`.
3. Now, Y tries to connect using `client-1` as id, username is `Y`.

What will happen?

1. Based on the clientId, the broker will think that X performs a **repeated connection attempt** which is [abnormal behavior](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718123).
2. Nothing extraordinary will happen. Y connects successfully as it **uses a different username**.
3. Nothing extraordinary will happen. The **broker will reject Y** connection attempt as the given clientId is already in use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `clientid` is the same, in MQTT, the spec says you must consider them to be the same client!
Probably Y should be connected using the `Id` and `X` should be disconnected.

This part is from the documentation:

> If validation is successful the Server performs the following steps.
>
> 1. If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client
>      [MQTT-3.1.4-2].
> 2. The Server MUST perform the processing of CleanSession that is described in section 3.1.2.4 [MQTT-3.1.4-3].
> 3. The Server MUST acknowledge the CONNECT Packet with a CONNACK Packet containing a zero return code [MQTT-3.1.4-4].
> 4. Start message delivery and keep alive monitoring.

Look [this documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718032) for more details.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, but it might be helpful to link and quote the [relevant part of the specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718032) (the key part is "If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client")

Comment: I have overlooked that part somehow, but it is surprising. A harmful client can force the broker to disconnect other clients then?