# Can a Mosquitto MQTT client forcibly disconnect another?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I've been wondering how an MQTT client could instruct the broker to disconnect a client by some means, in case I need to force-disconnect a client from my MQTT server (for example, if it's misbehaving somehow and not responding correctly).

A [previous question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/504/what-will-be-the-result-of-the-following-connection-scenario-in-an-mqtt-network) highlighted the possibility of just connecting with the same client ID as the client you want to kill, but this seems unreliable at best and I'm wondering if there's a more reliable option that will meet my needs:

- allows an authorised client to disconnect any other client from the network by client ID
- ideally, prevents unauthorised clients from disconnecting others (so that only the 'trusted' client can disconnect others)

Is there a feature that meets such requirements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly.

You could use an authentication plugin such as [mosquitto-auth-plug](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) to dynamically add users to a banned list and then force a disconnection by connecting with a duplicate client id.